# Possible reason why the notification is not removed

Tags: android

Notice that my notification icon is not always removed when my Service finish.
Thinking about possible reason for this.

My service start some nested threads and the deepest one puts a notification with icon
in the title bar of the phone.

I can see that onDestroy() in my Service is executed on stop Service.
I run the mNotificationManager.cancel(setServiceRunNotifNumber);

I cant see that i miss running the cancel to remove the notification.
This only happens sometimes that the notification remains after onDestroy().

Are there something else I forgot?
In what situation would the notification remain after Service killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That use to happen to me on 2.1 and lower. I noticed that if I killed my service, then waited 10 seconds and opened another app, my notification disappeared. I also noticed that if I killed my service and then restarted it right away, the icon wouldn't appear. This behaviour disappeared when my OS upgraded past 2.1.